# Programmatically Start Workflow Sharepoint 2013 Out of Range Exception

Tags: 2013, workflow, visual-studio, sharepoint-server, asp.net

I am trying to programmatically start my WF in Visual Studio and deploy it along with my solution into SharePoint 2013. The WF is in the same solution file as my ASP.NET web form and code behind.  I have this code below to start my WF

```
Try
   Dim web As SPWeb = SPContext.Current.Web
   Dim list As SPList = web.Lists("Workflow Tasks")

   Dim workflowServiceManager = New WorkflowServicesManager(web)
   Dim workflowSubscriptionService = workflowServiceManager.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService()

   Dim subscriptions = workflowSubscriptionService.EnumerateSubscriptionsByList(list)

    For Each workflowSubscription As Object In subscriptions
        Dim inputParameters = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
        workflowServiceManager.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService.StartWorkflowOnListItem(workflowSubscription, inputParameters)
    Next

Catch ex As Exception
    lblException.Text = ex.ToString()
End Try
```

And I am getting the following exception

```
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented WorkflowServicesManager.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService()
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Is this the correct way to start a WF programmatically using vb.net?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `SPContext.Current.Web` you have to instantiate a new `Web`. In C# I use:

```
SPSite site = new SPSite("http://myPortal/eventuallyTheSubsite");
SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
```

In VB.Net I think:

```
Dim site As SPSite = new SPSite("http://myPortal/eventuallyTheSubsite")
Dim web As SPWeb = site.OpenWeb()
```

The rest should be fine.

A little observation, personally I prefer to lookup the list using its Guid, since Guids can not change in time, the listname can, so:

```
SPList list = web.Lists[Guid.Parse("sdfsdf-sdg--sdfgh-sfdgh-fh-fdrgter")];
```